# comma-separated value to rows and split other colums also /2 or /3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

MeterSizeGroup   |   WrenchTime        |  DriveTime

```
      1,2,3 |  |        7.843 ||     5.099 |
```

I want to separate the comma delimited string into three rows as

MeterSizeGroup  |     WrenchTime |  DriveTime

```
          1 | |        2.614 |  |     1.699 |
          2 | |        2.614 |  |     1.699 |
          3 | |        2.614 |  |     1.699 |
```

please help me how to write a query for this type of split it has to split in such a way that wrech time and driver time also has to be split by 3 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9OBP.png)

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Did you research and try possible solutions?

Comment: i have tried and got splitting this metersizegroup column but i am unable to do the split of wrenchtime and drivetime values accordingly /3 or/2

Comment: if MeterSizeGroup column has incremental identity you can divide wrenchtime and driveTime by (Select Count(*) FROM table) statement in select